# Best choice to share data between apps in Wear OS

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

I want to know which option is worth it in order to exchange data between different apps in Wear OS.

I want to get users inputs from an app and make that data accessible to another app when it´s main activity starts. I saw that I could use local database, files, and many different possibilities but I don´t know which one is more efficient for Wear OS.

It´s not a lot of information, and data is gonna be hold in primitives. Some examples are: List os Strings that holds phone numbers, user information and so on.

Many thanks!

Comment: Did you check the [Send and sync data on Wear](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/)?

Comment: I did it! But finally I used SharedPreferences. Because I need to exchange same data between different apps inside every app in my project. All apps work as one. [I used this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35790331/7175503)

Comment: good job. you can post your answer to help other devs